# My ViewModel is causing multiple errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a viewmodel so i can display the information gathered from multiple models on one page, however im running into multiple errors ( as shown below)  For the models used are a part of a different project in my solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Along with displaying the information i am trying to create a dropdown for when a user is created they can select which device each user is using.

**User.cs (model**)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FaceToFace.Model
{
    public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string CodeName { get; set; }
        public bool UseBriefInstructions { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RegimeItem> RegimeItems { get; set; }
        public Device Device { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Grading> UserGradings { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            this.RegimeItems = new List<RegimeItem>();
            Device = new Device();
        }


    }
```

**Device.cs (model)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FaceToFace.Model
{
    public class Device
    {
        public int DeviceID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**UserDeviceViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
using FaceToFace.Model;

namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{
    public class UserDeviceViewModel
    {
        public UserDeviceViewModel()
        {
            User = new User();
            Users = new List<User>();
            Devices = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }

        public User UseBriefInstructions { get; set; }
        public Device Device { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public User CodeName { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> Devices { get; set; }
        public IList<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Views/Patient/Create.cshtml**

```
    @model FaceToFace.Model.User

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>User</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodeName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodeName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodeName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Device.Name, "Device")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User.Device.DeviceID, Model.Devices)
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**PatientController.cs**

```
 using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FaceToFace.Model;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using FaceToFaceWebsite.Models;

namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class PatientController : Controller
    {
        private F2FData db = new F2FData();

        //
        // GET: /Patient/
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(UserDeviceViewModel viewModelDevice)
        {

            var viewModel = new UserDeviceViewModel();

            viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "MAU110-10", Value = "1" });
            viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "MAU110-100", Value = "2" });
            viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "MAU110-101", Value = "3" });
            viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "MAU110-102", Value = "4" });
            viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "MAU110-103", Value = "5" });

            viewModel.Users.AddRange(db.Users.ToList());

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        // GET: /Patient/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            // was ViewBag.DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "Name");
            ViewBag.DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Patient/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UserID,CodeName,UseBriefInstructions")] User user, Device device)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //db.Devices = user.Device.DeviceID;
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "Name", user.Device.DeviceID);
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Patient/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            //removed   user.Device.DeviceID
            ViewBag.DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "Name");
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Patient/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "UserID,CodeName,UseBriefInstructions")] User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "Name", user.Device.DeviceID);
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Patient/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
            //User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            //if (user == null)
            //{
            //    return HttpNotFound();
            //}
            //return View(user);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Patient/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            db.Users.Remove(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

I will leave out edit view to avoid further spam it basically contains similar functionality to create, however I am getting multiple errors now.  I have fixed a few I believe. For the dropdown (create) i am getting this error:

**'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments**

For the `viewModel.Devices.Add` in patient controller i am getting:

**The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.Add(System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem)' has some invalid arguments**

along with:

**Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' to 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem'**

and finally below that i am receiving an error from AddRange (PatientController):

**'System.Collections.Generic.IList' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

*** **UPDATE** ***

**Change to the PatientController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index(UserDeviceViewModel viewModelDevice)
        {
            var viewModel = new UserDeviceViewModel(); 

            List<UserDeviceViewModel> viewModelList = new List<UserDeviceViewModel>();
            viewModelDevice.Users.AddRange(db.Users.ToList());
            return View(viewModelList);
        }
```

**UserDeviceViewModel.cs**

```
namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{
    public class UserDeviceViewModel
    {
        public UserDeviceViewModel()
        {
            Device = new Device();
            User = new User();
            Users = new List<User>();
            Devices = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }

        public Device Device { get; set; }
        public Device Name { get; set; }
        public Device DeviceID { get; set; }

        public User UseBriefInstructions { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public User UserID { get; set; }
        public User CodeName { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Devices { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml  (view)**

```
@model IEnumerable<FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.UserDeviceViewModel>
@*@model IEnumerable<FaceToFace.Model.User>*@

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Your Patients</h2>

    @*Showing @Model.Count() users*@

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Add New User", "Create")
    </p>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CodeName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Device.Name)*@Device
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Device.DeviceID)
            </th>

        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodeName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Device.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Device.DeviceID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.UserID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.UserID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

I have got it to run without errors however my original problem of no data from the db is showing on the index view.  It also does not show when i create a new user either.

Comment: IList doesn't have an AddRange method, but List does. You'll have to specifically use the List class if you want AddRange.

Comment: For the rest, you have invalid arguments. Check the values you're passing against the expected types!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for
>   'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

For the above error, `DeviceID` is an int it needs to be a string and `Devices` needs to be an `IEnumerable`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User.Device.DeviceID, Model.Devices)
```

So change public `IList<SelectListItem> Devices { get; set; }` to `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Devices { get; set; }`

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.Add(System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>        The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.Add(System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem)'
>   has some invalid arguments

The two above errors there is some kind of miss-match between references, you controller has the `using System.Web.Mvc` the view is somehow picking up `System.Web.WebPages.Html`, check that there is no `@using System.Web.WebPages.Html` in the view.

> System.Collections.Generic.IList' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Change your `Users` property to be an `IEnumerable` instead:

```
public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thankyou Hutch, sorry i havent replied sooner i've been quite ill.  I am still getting the FaceToFace.Model.User does not contain a definition for 'AddRange'.

I am also getting getting one for <System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem> does not contain a definition for 'Add'... in the patient controller also.

Comment: @Nilmag No probs, for the add you need to change this `IList<SelectListItem> Devices` to this `List<SelectListItem> Devices` and this `IList<User> Users { get; set; }` to this `List<User> Users { get; set; }`

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  I have managed to get it working without errors.  I have provided an update to the question showing what i've changed.  However it does not show the data that is already in the database nor show users i create.

Comment: What i have gathered is that when i create new users it updates the db with the new user (it does not add the device though)

Comment: @Nilmag I'm not sure what that could be. I would create a new question containing just the info around that. You will get a lot more people answering that way. As there is a lot of content people may be put off answering in here.

Comment: Ah i didnt realise, that. Thanks again for your help.  I'll keep testing ideas before i post again.  I need exhaust my possible options before i ask.

Comment: @Nilmag No probs, I only know that from being on here. Often easy to re-create issues get answered quicker. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

For the DropDownList (you already declare the User model):

```
@model FaceToFace.Model.User
....
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Device.DeviceID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DeviceID)
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry i havent replied sooner i've been quite ill. I am still getting the FaceToFace.Model.User does not contain a definition for 'AddRange'. I am also getting getting one for <System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem> does not contain a definition for 'Add'... in the patient controller also.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I have managed to get it working without errors. I have provided an update to the question showing what i've changed. However it does not show the data that is already in the database nor show users i create.  What i have gathered is that when i create new users it updates the db with the new user (it does not add the device though)